# How do I redirect console output from a node run script in my packages.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash, package.json, console.log

### The goal: capture console output in a log file.

All I have are `console.log()` operations, and I know how to use `>`, so I would expect this to be simple enough, right?

### The Setup: my package.json scripts

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "node ./lib/es6_global/test/Main.bs.js",
    "test-ci": "npm run test > log.log"
},
```

So, seems simple.

### Expected Result

I would expect the `test` command to output to the console and the `test-ci` command to output to the log.

### Actual Result

```sh
$ node ./lib/es6_global/test/Main.bs.js # outputs expected output to terminal.
$ node ./lib/es6_global/test/Main.bs.js > log.log # outputs expected output to log file.
$ npm run test # prints two lines specifying the test script and then outputs expected output to terminal. 
$ npm run test-ci # prints two lines specifying the test script, creates the log file, but does not appear to write to it.
```

I'm at a loss for why I can't output to the file from within a script. Like, it clearly *thinks* its parsing the `>` in the script because it doesn't output to the terminal, and it creates the log file if it doesn't exist. It just doesn't appear to write to it.

What's wild is I can enter the full command into the console with the output redirected and it does exactly what I expect. What is it about putting it inside a "run" command that silences my output?